# Android Facebook SDK - get only certain friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder for a user to be able to send out requests.
In the onComplete-method I don't get the names of the users that the requests have been sent out too (right?) - only the facebook ids.

Therefore I was thinking of using Request.newMyFriendsRequest, but I would want to send in a list of the user ids to fetch (as I don't want it to fetch all the friends - this to limit the traffic).

Is this possible? There is a setParameter-metod for the request, but I have no clue of which parameter to set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. It looks like everyone uses the WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder and my issue is that it only returns the ids of the selected users, when at that step I need to create my own server invitations which at least needs to have user's uid and name. So I tried the FriendsPickerFragment and that guy can returns you a nice List<GraphUser> when the user presses on Done button, but after that I do not know how to create the app' requests.